# Are there any adventures for younger children?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, policy

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/12011/768

I am a bit confused. Is it now the policy to close questions just because they have the wrong answers to the questions? My question was not an RPG I am only interested in adventures, I can create my own RPG. I thought the we where supposed to comment and down vote answers that where not on topic. Not merge the question wholesale.

Now you have made your point and moved the questions can I have my question reopened, so I can get the answers I asked for.

Comment: This is what Mxy said in chat *"You asked adventures, but then someone said "or RPGs?" and you said yes, and then all the answers were dupes. It's easier to merge when that happens than what, delete all the answers? Like I say, feel free to reopen with adventure only scope."* That said I can't seem to case re-open vote. I'm not sure why.

Comment: As all the comments have gone, I can't double check but that was not what I meant. Sometimes things get misunderstood. I also can't vote to reopen it, I expect it has some level of block on it.

Comment: I think it's to do with the way merge works, and nothing intentional on Mxy's part. As such I think we ought to wait and see what he says.

Comment: I don't really want to re-ask the question. I was happy with my original question. It only need to be closed with a polite message say that the topic needed discussion on meta or chat before it would be reopened. This is what really annoys me about all the SE sites. This high handed management style.

Comment: @DavidAllanFinch The problem is, your question was fine in principle but resulted in the wrong answers. We could have gone through a discussion process, but at the end of the day the choices were the same: Lose one highly upvoted question (that had failed to attract the answers it was looking for), or lose a number of highly upvoted answers (that didn't actually answer the question). Given that the question needed some tweaking anyway (in hindsight), the choice seemed pretty clear to us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I attempted to re-open your question, which no longer shows as closed, but I am unable to add an answer.  I'll ask the technical team.  Worst case you may have to delete this question and re ask.  *I think at this point you just need to ask again.  Please note that you're asking specifically for adventures, not systems.*

We'll try to find a better way to police people answering the wrong question in the future.

Comment: Thanks @C. Ross

Answer (score 2):

That's right, your question originally said adventures but you explicitly said yes to "or RPGs" in the comments as clarification. Then you immediately got 6-8 answers, all RPGs, that were all appropriate to the other question. "Mouse Guard, 4e, etc..." Your clarification led it to be a duplicate; those answers weren't wrong or accidental.

The original question can't be reopened after being merged. Merges move all the answers and their votes over to the other question.

You can cut and paste your paragraph of question about adventures into a new question easily. It'd take less time than crafting a meta question to complain. In fact, it would take less time than a close and discussion and cleanup and reopen. Reopen the same question, just keep it on track to adventures. 30 seconds of work, problem solved.

The other option was to close it and wait, but you had generated a bunch of new good answers legitimately for the duplicate question, so the right thing to do is merge. Otherwise you re-clarify your question and have 6-8 "bad answers," some of which get voted back up due to people being unclear on things.

I understand you weren't there to see it, and that wasn't your intent, but there was a lot of traffic on that question and they were all RPG system answers. There were no adventure answers and none were going to happen; the question had clearly "converted."